# cant start User Profile Synchronization Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory

i have a sharepoint entreprise 2013, sql server 2014 .
My goal here is to start the user profile synchronise service . 
I check all thing : permission, ADSI, datebase ... my farm account seems great , and it doesnt start also ,

So my actual sharepoint version is : 15.0.4569.1000.
Any idea to do the synchronisation

Comment: is it stuck in starting ?

Comment: Yep! - Follow Harbar's guide, and don't skip any step. If you do, you will fail (as I've done many times before you). See http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Comment: make sure  to start UPSs via farm account and put it in your administrator group during start

Comment: @M.Qassas fron starting to stopped ,

Comment: yes @M.Qassas , I checked all that, my farm account has all permisison ,delegate control ....

Comment: please double check if it's added to the local administrator group or not ?

Comment: also you must restart SharePoint timer service if you have already added farm account to local administrator group

Comment: If you do as @BennySkogberg said, follow Harbar's guide, it never fails.

Comment: as to catch exact error, Enable the Verbose Logging...Then try to start the UPa SYnc, Now wait  for stop....Now check the ULS log on the server where you trying to start the service...You will get the root cause.

Comment: you are right @WaqasSarwarMCSE it was related to SQL server .l i installed CU september 2014 because i use sql2014second , i recreate the user application . and it works ,

Comment: That's great, could you please add that as answer not comment so that community get benefits and actual solution.

Comment: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that

- You are using the Farm Account to start UPSs.
- The Farm account is added to local administrator group during starting UPS service.

**Note:**

- After adding the farm account to local administrator group , you must restart the SharePoint 2013 Timer service.
- Adding farm account to local administrator group is required only to start the User Profile Synchronization service. After the User Profile Synchronization service is started, you can remove the farm account from the Administrators group. for more details check.

for more details check [User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/)

Comment: no chance , i check all this !

Comment: i installed the CU, and it works , the log help me ; error related to data base https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ianragusa/2014/06/23/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-start-the-user-profile-synchronization-service/

Comment: Great Job , I really appreciate your useful feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

this how i resolve the problem:it's a combination of the answer and the comment on top:

-First , need to flow  step by step.
[User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/.)

-Second , if you are on sql2012 , it should works fine , 
but if you use sql2014 and the log file has some Data base error related to sql you need to install some CU : [SharePoint 2013: Unable to Start the User Profile Synchronization Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ianragusa/2014/06/23/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-start-the-user-profile-synchronization-service/)

Hope it help .